# Rich Snippets and MovingCompany Schema

Tags: seo, schema.org

i am trying to implement rich snippets on company website. Main business is moving services and storage. As i know there is

```
  "@context": "https://schema.org",

 "@type": "MovingCompany",
```

All the required fields re filled like name, address, phone, logo etc. Via rich snippet tools that code is validated. But i have several doubts.

Can i use Organization schema also on the same page as MovingCompany with similar data? can google penalize me for that? maybe some overuse of schemas?
I notice also that other moving websites don't use reviews schemas on homepage or general pages (about us, contact etc.), only on services or city pages. Can i use freely general review score from different sources like yelp, trustpilot on the all pages? I tried adding review schema on one website and then all the pages got same review score, stars etc. Should that be avoided?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i use Organization schema also on the same page as MovingCompany
> with similar data?

The type [`MovingCompany`](https://schema.org/MovingCompany) is the sub-type of the type `Organization` and has all the properties for the organization. It hardly makes sense to duplicate these properties.

> Can i use freely general review score from different sources like
> yelp, trustpilot on the all pages?

Do not do it. This is contrary to the **[guidelines of Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#technical-guidelines)**:

> Don't aggregate reviews from other websites.
>
> If the review snippet is for a local business or an organization, you must follow > these additional guidelines:  Ratings must be sourced directly from users.

Comment: Regarding organization/movingCompany schema its clear, its enough to use MovingCompany then. Regarding reviews i read that document but still i am confused. On my website i have real user reviews submited thru emails or forms. And those reviews are reviews for that business or movingCompany. So if i have 5 real reviews its fine to pull them into schema and display them as agregatedreviews?

Comment: I see no reason which to prevent your markup from creating reviews from real users.

Comment: Collecting your own reviews puts you foul of another guideline: "Pages using LocalBusiness or any other type of Organization structured data are ineligible for star review feature if the entity being reviewed controls the reviews about itself. For example, a review about entity A is placed on the website of entity A, either directly in their structured data or through an embedded third-party widget."